# Jquery to find inputbox by ID to get value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find inputbox in my .asmx view file to get the value. But I don;t know how can I find that by below jquery code

my View

```
  <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="100" class="col-label">
                <span> Employee Name</span>
            </td>
            <td class="col-label">
                <input type="text" maxlength="200" style="margin-left: 0;" name="Name" id="Name"
                    class="required" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="col-label">
                Employee Description
            </td>
            <td class="col-label">
                <textarea id="Description" name="Description" class="required" cols="15" rows="2"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Now can I use jquery find function to seach for that inputbox?

```
var input = myview.find();
```

Comment: `$('#Name')` ...?

Comment: Can find() can search directly my id `('#Name')`?

Comment: According to the docs, yes: https://api.jquery.com/find/  What happens when you *try*?

Comment: @user1413 Isn't that one of the most basic jQuery selectors? Why do you think it can't search like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input box can be called using id in jquery:

```
$('#Name')
```